# Why do some pronoun nominatives look like vocatives?

Tags: language-evolution, morphology, pronouns

The forms *ipse*, *ille*, and *iste* look like vocatives instead of nominatives, and one would expect to see *ipsus*, *illus*, and *istus* instead.
In fact, [*ipsus*](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23ipsus%23) is attested but far rarer than *ipse*, but the other two forms seem to be entirely absent.
Is there a reason for this unusual morphology?
Is it related to the vocative (perhaps having a similar origin) or is the similarity coincidental?
Is there something analogous in other languages or with other pronouns, or anything else that might shed light on these unexpected forms?

Some pronoun singular nominatives are quite wild (*is, qui, illud, …*), but the three I brought up are only mildly weird, and therefore I hope that an explanation actually exists.
If I remember correctly, the singular masculine vocative of the second declension is obtained from the pure stem (without the nominative ending *-s*), with a vowel change *o>e*.
Any evidence for tendency to drop the *-s* for pronouns in singular masculine nominative would be interesting if that is the case.

It appears that *ipsus* was more popular in pre-classical Latin, and kkm remarks in a comment that *olle* and *ollus* are attested for *ille* in old Latin.
This gives the impression that the expected *-us* ending was there but was later lost.
Any insight as to why or how this happened would be great.

Comment: Iirc *ipsus* is attested in older Latin. But I don't think *_illus_ or *_istus_ are.

Comment: @Draconis I checked PHI and indeed *ipsus* is attested, also classically, but *illus* and *istus* aren't. I updated the question.

Comment: *olle* and *ollus* are attested in old Latin for *ille*, if I am not mistaken. In general, a connection to voc. looks rather doubtful. The *se* and *te* reflexes are very transparent; and IIRC there is a relation of "distance" of demonst. to the grammatical person in many PIE daughter languages (this = near me, that (far) = near him, that (near) = near you = *is* + *te*).

Comment: @kkm I agree, they are unlikely to be directly connected to vocatives. But still the question remains: why not *-us*? The old attestations are interesting, as it makes it seem like the ending has changed.

Comment: @kkm, Joonas, what if -e is derived from/has a common ancestor with the adverbial ending instead?

Comment: @Rafael I can't rule that out, but one would have to explain why the adverbial *-e* is long while the vocative/pronoun *-e* is short.

Comment: Alas, quantity. That's the problem one gets when not learning classical from the beginning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Because the second element is the **PIE deictic pronoun *so-/*to-**, which gave Latin -se;

so we may reconstruct PIE nom. sg. mas. as *só (Weiss, p. 337).

- *is-so > *is-se > ipse (Weiss, pp. 346-347); cf. de Vaan *e(s)-pe-so > *ispse > ipse;
- *is-to (or *es-to) > *is-te > iste (Weiss, p. 345);
- *ol-so > olle > ille.